Search a Particular Item from API in react
Here I am creating food recipe app in React using an API, I got all recipes from an API.
Now I want to particular dish from API as a dish type wise,
but I didn't get any data from an API.
Here is my App.js Code:
function App() {
  return (
   <>
   <BrowserRouter>
   <Category/>
   <Pages/>
   </BrowserRouter>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;



There Main component for Variety :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Variety () {
  const [variety,setVariety]=useState([]);
  let params=useParams();

  const getVariety=async (name) =>{
    const data=await fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&variety=${name}`)
    const recipe = await data.json();
    setVariety(recipe.result);
  };

useEffect(()=>{
  getVariety(params.type);
},[params.type]);

  return 
    <Grid>
      {variety.map((item)=>{
        return(
          <Card key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.image} alt=""/>
            <h4>{item.title}</h4>
          </Card>
        )
      })}
    </Grid>
  
}

const Grid =styled.div`
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(20rem,1fr));
grid-gap:3rem
`
const Card=styled.div`
img{
width:100%;
border-radius:2rem;
}

a{
text-decoration:none;
}

h4{
text-align:center;
margin:2rem;
}

`

Here is the Variety type of Dish :
import {FaPizzaSlice,FaHamburger } from 'react-icons/fa';
import {GiNoodles,GiChopsticks } from 'react-icons/gi';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

export default function Category() {
  return (
    <List>
      <NavLink to={'/Variety/Italian'}> 
        <FaPizzaSlice/>
        <h4>Italian</h4>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink  to={'/Variety/American'}>
        <FaHamburger />
        <h4>American</h4>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink  to={'/Variety/Chinese'}>
        <GiNoodles/>
        <h4>Chinese</h4>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink  to={'/Variety/Japanese'}>
        <GiChopsticks/>
        <h4>Japanese</h4>
        </NavLink>
    </List>
  )
}


And the last one is Show the Variety into the URL for searching Particular Variety:
import React from 'react'
import Home from './Home'
import {Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Variety from './Variety ';

function Pages() {
  return (
   
      <Routes>
        <Route path='' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/Variety/:type' element={<Variety/>}/>
      </Routes>
    
  )
}

export default Pages

This is a Home Page of Website

Now I'm Clicking on the Italian Dish, But Cannot Get Any dish

Please help if someone has any solution!

have you tried to change
return

{variety.map((item)=>{
return(


{item.title}

)
})}

to
return

{variety.map(item)=>
(


{item.title}

)
}


If you are trying to fetch one specific item from the api data you can use find() method. use it similar to map method like data.find((item)=>{ dish_name == searchTerm } ) modify this as per your requirement wherever you need it. Also, you can modify the conditional inside find() method I just wrote that as a sample.

What exactly is your question, or what specific issue do you have? Please [edit] to clarify the problem.

just make sure the return statement is enclosed () within the parentheses especially when returning jsx.


return (
    <Grid>
      {variety.map((item)=>{
        return(
          <Card key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.image} alt=""/>
            <h4>{item.title}</h4>
          </Card>
        )
      })}
    </Grid>
);



